How I can make the upload of multiple files (with categories) as smooth as possible?
I'm working on a data capture feature where users are able to upload multiple files at a time. The point is they are obliged to categorize each file. The requirement is to give them as much freedom as possible so there might be cases when users want to attach single file to multiple categories upon upload. Also uploading multiple files and categorize them should be possible. Is there a better way to do it than after dragging the files into the drop area (or browsing them) we show dropdowns or chips (tags) next to each file so users can decide before they click 'Upload'?
PS the exact number of categories is 15 and it won't change in the future.
Draft designs for reference.


You want to find out if there is "a better way to do it". Can you describe what "better" means in this context? Please aim for specific answers. What is for example the problem with the current design?

The problem I see is that for every file user needs to click on the dropdown and scroll for desired category/categories. With many files being uploaded at once it makes a lot of clicking. I was thinking about the tags and putting them next to each of the file. Then user clicks only those with matching category. But this would create a lot of clutter (15 categories). I'm looking for any ideas that will help to achieve assigning categories faster but also to not confuse the users or clutter the interface.

Generally it is very difficult to optimize for two actions/interactions that don't have a most common or best/worst case scenarios. This is because most design decisions involve tradeoffs and it is often difficult to make it work well for all users and use cases.
In this scenario, you want to give them maximum freedom while also ensuring that category labels are applied. Maximum freedom and a strict requirement doesn't really go hand-in-hand.
A compromise might be to display the uploaded files in a table UI format that enables batch operations if you really want to reduce the time it takes to apply category labels to multiple files. But if the users doesn't really even know what the most efficient way might be to upload a bunch of files and apply labels to them, then I don't think you can come up with a one-size-fits-all solution either. Sometimes it will be easier to upload one file at a time and label it, sometimes it will be easier to upload a bunch of files and batch apply a label to all of them.
You may also need to go back to the core functional requirements and find out that in fact you are limited in how this feature can work, because usually when you can put in solid requirements and constraints, the solution becomes a bit more obvious.
